# Classpath for ant plugins when using ANTBuilder from Gradle

Tags: ant, gradle

I have a `build.gradle` file which loads [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) (downloading it from upstream Maven), and then loads an Ant build.xml file which requires PMD:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'pmd:pmd:4.2.5'
  }
}
ant.importBuild 'shared-build.xml'
```

However, the Ant import fails:

```
taskdef class net.sourceforge.pmd.ant.PMDTask cannot be found
using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
  at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:551)
[...]
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder.importBuild(DefaultAntBuilder.groovy:76)
```

How can [Gradle's ant integration](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/ant.html) be instructed to make this available?

Comment: Does the Ant build have the same problem, or does it work when executed directly?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser the ant build works when executed directly -- however, this is with a local installation of ant which has had PMD directly added to its default classpath.

Comment: ...frankly, I've already found a reasonable workaround for the issue (which involved updating shared-build.xml to specify an explicit classpath when dealing with PMD)... but I'd prefer to be able to use the Gradle-downloaded instance even so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no straighforward way to do it, as Gradle does not offer any API support for this. So you need to hack it some way.

For example, you can do something like this, right before calling ant.importBuild

```
org.apache.tools.ant.Project.class.classLoader.addURL( file('libs/somelib.jar').toURI().toURL() )
```

Alternatively you can call the addURL() method with the paths you get through the Gradle's dependency resolution (again, this should be executed before the call to ant.importBuild).

```
configurations { someconf }
dependencies { someconf "org.eclipse.jdt:ecj:3.6.1" }

def antClassLoader = org.apache.tools.ant.Project.class.classLoader
configurations.someconf.each { File f ->
    antClassLoader.addURL(f.toURI().toURL())
}
```

Of course, another solution would be to have the classpath defined inside your build.xml file so you won't have to do anything from Gradle.

See some input here http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/How-to-add-to-classpath-for-ant-importBuild-td3268631.html