# Delombok'ing source code with added jar dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, lombok

I am unable to delombok my Java source code, apparently due to jar dependencies that the project has, and I don't understand why. There are two jar files that have to be committed to the repo to tag along, and they are added to the project in the `dependencies` node of the `build.gradle` file by adding the line `compile files('myproj1.jar')`. So, the relevant part of the `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
dependencies {
     compile files('myproj1.jar')
     compile files('myproj2.jar')

     .....
}
```

When I run the delombok task I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':delombok'.
> taskdef class lombok.delombok.ant.Tasks$Delombok cannot be found
   using the classloader AntClassLoader[/path/to/repo/myproj1.jar:/path/to/repo/myproj2.jar]
```

Why would delombok task be using the `AntClassLoader` from the jar files?

I have tried the delombok'ing code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997441/delombok-using-gradle)

Here is the task from my `build.gradle` file

```
def srcJava = 'src/main/java'
def srcDelomboked = 'build/src-delomboked'

task delombok {
    // delombok task may depend on other projects already being compiled
    dependsOn configurations.compile.getTaskDependencyFromProjectDependency(true, "compileJava")

    // Set up incremental build, must be made in the configuration phase (not doLast)
    inputs.files file(srcJava)
    outputs.dir file(srcDelomboked)

    doLast {
        FileCollection collection = files(configurations.compile)
        FileCollection sumTree = collection + fileTree(dir: 'bin')

        ant.taskdef(name: 'delombok', classname: 'lombok.delombok.ant.Tasks$Delombok', classpath: configurations.compile.asPath)
        ant.delombok(from:srcJava, to:srcDelomboked, classpath: sumTree.asPath)
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to delombok my Java source code as part of the build process so that when the project is compiled there are no dependencies on Lombok.

Answer (score 2):

So after continued trial an error, I have a working implementation. To answer my own question, the problem has nothing to do with the additional Jar files. Rather, when gradle runs the `delombok` task, the classes in the lombok jar are not in the classpath of the `org.gradle.api.AntBuilder` (ie, the `ant` task), and so it does not have a reference to `lombok.delombok.ant.Tasks$Delombok` anywhere (which seems obvious at this point, but not at the time).

The solution thus far has been to add those references in from `configurations.compile`

Combining code snippits from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997441) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220099) you can do it with something like this:

```
def srcDelomboked = 'build/src-delomboked'

task delombok {
    description 'Delomboks the entire source code tree'

    def srcJava = 'src/main/java'

    inputs.files files( srcJava )
    outputs.dir file( srcDelomboked )

    doFirst {
        ClassLoader antClassLoader = org.apache.tools.ant.Project.class.classLoader
        def collection = files( configurations.compile + configurations.testCompile )
        def sumTree = collection + fileTree( dir: 'bin' )
        sumTree.forEach { File file ->
            antClassLoader.addURL(file.toURI().toURL())
        }

        ant.taskdef( name: 'delombok', classname: 'lombok.delombok.ant.Tasks$Delombok',
                classpath: configurations.compile.asPath + configurations.testCompile.asPath )
        ant.delombok( from: srcJava, to: srcDelomboked, classpath: sumTree.asPath )
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java { srcDirs = [ srcDelomboked ] }  //blow away the old source sets so that we only use the delomboked source sets
    }
    test {
        java { srcDirs += [ srcDelomboked ] } //but add those new source sets to the tests so that their references are available at test time
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn(delombok)

bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'com.myproj.MyMainClass' // you will need this if its a Spring Boot project
}
```

Hope this helps whomever else needs to delombok their code.

Comment: The post you based your implementation on is pretty old and that's probably the culprit. I'm using a gradle plugin, which makes delomboking pretty simple, but is obsolete in the meantime, too. I'd start with the [lombok page](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle) linking to a newer plugin. OTOH your home brew solution needs no plugin at all, so +1.

Comment: @maaartinus so, based on the link you sent, it looks like if I just change the lombok dependency to `compileOnly`, it will just delombok it for me?

Comment: No idea. I'm not using delombok ATM (I dropped it during the last big upgrade and haven"t need it since).